# Python how to extend list of custom model

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python and I come from a java background.

I am working on a sdk which internally invokes some rest end points , and we r exposing client and methods. I have done the sdk in Java. Now I am doing the same in python. I dont write the code manually. I use [swagger-code-gen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) . So I dont have much flexibility on model structure. For Models which extend a list of other models, the generated code has compilation errors. So I am trying to fix those particular cases.

In java we have code :

```
public class Errors extends ArrayList<ErrorsInner> {
 //---
}
```

In python I want to re-generate same code. I have tried below options . but nothing seems to be working properly. :

1. class Errors(list):

   This is not a proper solution because Errors should properly contain paramters of ErrorsInner as well. So after it gets deserialized , I can find the properties in this model.
2. from typing import List

   class Errors(List[ErrorsInner]):

I should create "Errors" model such that it will be easily de-serialized and serialized.

what are the alternatives available in python?

Comment: Python is not a statically typed language like Java. Just use a `list` and have your errors as `tuples, named tuples or dicts`. Why bother with classes unless you have a state to maintain.  You should also update the question to include problem you are trying to solve rather than how you are trying to solve it.

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera i have updated the question, please revisit

Comment: What do you call "models" ? Classes ? And what does "Errors should properly contain paramters of ErrorsInner as well" means ? Do you mean "should inherit from ErrorsInner" ?  Terminology has a reason: making sure we all know what we're talking about, so if you don't use proper terminology we can't really understand the question.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Errors is just an example name. this issue we have for all custom models where the model extends list of another model. Models need a structure. to give that structure we need a class. So model is of that "class" type.

Comment: So why do you insist on talking about "models" when you want to talk about classes ??? Also: "where the model extends list of another model" doesn't make sense - either your "list of another model" is a custom class and then you only have to inherit from this class (assuming "extends" means "inherit from" - which is the accepted terminology), or it's a plain list (python `list`) and then it's totally disjoint from your "model" classes - a Python list is a just a list, it doesn't care what it contains.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ur last lines were helpful.. My terminologies are biased from java.. May be that's its not making sense. sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make two classes:

```
class MyError(Error):
    def magic_func(): pass

class MyErrorList(list, ErrorsInner):
    def my_func(): pass

l = MyErrorList(MyError(), MyError(), MyError())
l.my_func()
l.append(MyError())
for e in l:
    e.magic_func();
```

Python itself doesn't prevent you from doing `l.append("I am stupid")` but you can check with `isinstance(e, MyError)`.

Python can "extend" multiple classes.

Comment: I have ipdated the question. Please re-visit

Comment: I have ipdated the answer. Please re-visit

Comment: It would of course help if you told us what is in `ErrorsInner`

Comment: You don't need ErrorsInner as a super class for multiple inheritance in MyErrorList. Java's generics stuff are not really needed in Python because you can pretty much put anything in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate why your first example does not work? You can do:

```
class Errors(list):
    pass
```

And then in code:

```
In [2]: errors = Errors()
In [3]: errors.append('wtf')
In [4]: errors
Out[4]: ['wtf']
In [5]: errors.pop()
Out[5]: 'wtf'
```

Above, `Errors` will be extending from `list` type.

Comment: This is not a proper solution for me. This model is supposed hold the response coming from api. Errors should properly contain paramters of ErrorsInner as well. So after it gets deserialized , I can find the properties in this model.

Comment: " Errors should properly contain paramters of ErrorsInner as well" doesn't make any sense. Please use well-established terminology if you expect anyone to understand your question.